# Insert new Record into SubTable on Form With Value Equal to Parent Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form (parent) called "Bidder Report" that has a SubTable Called "Table.Items" located in it. When I insert a new record into the table I would like to have one of the fields prepopulated with a  value from the parent form. Each Record in the parent contains a numerical "ID" value. Each record in the Items table contains a "Winning Bidder" field that should populate to match the "ID" value of the parent.

Now what I think is throwing me is that the "Winning Bidder" field in the table is a multi-valued field in access. That is, multiple winning bidders can "win" an item.

Is it possible to insert a new record in the Items table with a prepopulated winning bidder value equal to that of the parent form? My guess is this requires a vba SQL statement but have been unable to figure out the syntax. Thank you.

Comment: _multiple winning bidders can "win" an item_ doesn't correlate to _a prepopulated winning bidder value_.

Comment: With the multi value field I get a dropdown of options. Is it possible to preselect one of those options based on the parent form's ID?

Comment: I would convert the MV field to a normal combobox and a subtable. An MV field is a dead end.

Comment: If I do convert to a combo box what is the best way to preselect a value from the combobox based on the parent form's ID?

Comment: Use the _AfterUpdate_ event of the combox to set the value of the child field.

Comment: I do not think this will work as comboboxes allow only one selection and a listbox while allowing multiple selections cannot store a value when multiple selection is enabled.

Comment: That's right. You will have to reconsider your concept.

Comment: You probably just need to use the `LinkChildFields` and `LinkMasterFields` properties to connect the parent form to the sub *table*.